# Sonarqube project level measures tab blank

Tags: sonarqube5.6

Running Sonarqube 5.6.1 MSBuild scanner C#/javascript with mutiple projects with a MSSqlServer db.  The global measures tab displays all appropriate projects as expected, however drilling down into individual projects - the measures tab there is blank.

All plugins are updated, nothing custom or esoteric is installed - (C#, SonarJS, Git, Timeline).  Server restarted.

The scanner log has no errors and indicates SUCCESS.  All of the other tabs [home,issues code, dashboards] are appropriately updated with the latest scan results as expected.

Is there some plugin that's required to enable the measures tab?  Some additional configuration required to select what is displayed on this page Installing Sonarqube locally and running with internally db with out of the box settings the measures tab is populated as expected with Maintainability, Duplications, Size, Complexity, Documentation, Issues.

Any troubleshooting ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Measures tab is built-in, it doesn't require any plugin.

Reports of blank Measures page often involved the following situation:

- reverse-proxy used in front of SonarQube server
- reverse-proxy has a setting controlling the maximum URL length
- when loading the Measures page, that setting caused an HTTP request to be kicked-out, which caused the page to be empty
- increasing the maximum allowed URL length improved the situation